# Handle chrome link clicked event

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm writing a chrome history extension, and I was wondering if there's a way to detect when the user clicks a link.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this? I'm having the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of injecting listeners to every single link via Content-Script, can you utilize: [chrome.tabs.onUpdated](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tabs.html#event-onUpdated) event? There are many [events](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tabs.html#events) as well.

But since you stated history, you can use the [onVisited](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/history.html#event-onVisited) event, which fires when a URL is visited.

It would be better to utilize the extension framework instead of relying on content scripts all the time which might become messy.